# How do I create Word document from all messages in a Thunderbird folder?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap

I have a gmail account and I usually read my messages in Thunderbird (IMAP).

I have created a particular filter in gmail, which has become a folder in Thunderbird.

I have located my thunderbird profile on one of my computers, and have located the file corresponding to the particular folder.  (From the profile,

I had to go to ImapMail and then imap.googlemail.com.)  It has no suffix, and the file type is called "File".

My end goal is to create a Word document of all the messages in that folder.

I tried "edit with notepad++" and got a lot of nonsense.

Would this be easier in the browser instead of thunderbird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I create a Word doc from all the messages in a folder

You can use the [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) Thunderbird add-on to export all of the message in a folder to a variety of different formats.

Several of these formats can be converted or imported into a word document.

[image]

---

#### ImportExportTools 3.2.1

> About this Add-on
>
> This extension allows the user to export and import folders and
> messages with lots of options, for example:
>
> Tools Menu --> ImportExportTools or Context menu on folders panel -->
> Import/Export
>
> - export of folder in a single file (mbox format), with also the subfolders if you want;
> - export of all messages in single files (eml or html or plain text format or CSV), with attachments and an index;
> - export of all messages in PDF format (required ImportExportTools 3.0 or higher)
> - export of all messages in one single plain text file;
> - export of index of the messages in a folder (HTML or CSV format);
> - mbox files import;
> - eml files import;
> - emlx files import;
> - import of all the eml files existing in a directory;
> - export of all files of all mail files of the profile (just from the "Tools" menu);
> - import of a saved profile (just from the "Tools" menu, required ImportExportTools 3.0 or higher, not available for Seamonkey)
> - search with various criteria and export messages;
> - import SMS from the programs "SMS Backup and Restore" for Android and Nokia2AndroidSMS;
>
> File menu --> Save selected messages or Context menu of thread panel
> --> Save selected messages
>
> - saving multiple messages in eml/html/plain text format with just one click;
> - saving multiple messages in PDF format with just one click (required ImportExportTools 3.0 or higher)
>
> Message menu --> Copy to clipboard or Context menu of thread panel -->
> Copy to clipboard
>
> - copy the message or all headers to clipboard.
>
> Context menu on an EML attachment
>
> - import file in the folder

Source [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/)

Comment: I thought that add-on wasn't working -- thanks, I'll try it again.  Thanks for the instructions!